# Set a js variable in FireBug console

Tags: javascript, console, global-variables, firebug

In Firefox's FireBug console, why does this happen?

```
>>> a = 1
1

>>> var a = 50
undefined

>>> a 
50
```

I'm just trying to learn me some js!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var ...` is a statement.

Statements do not have values, so the console prints `undefined` as the result of the statement.

Comment: so `document.write('hi');` should also return undefined (if it didn't refresh the browser)?

Comment: @DonnyP: That's different.  `document.write(...)` is an expression, not a statement, so it has a value.  However, the `document.write()` function returns undefined.